# Java conditional statement

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

I am using jcreator to practice java language. I came up with a conditional statement in which if the user input is = "test" it will print an "okay!" message. This is my code:

```
class conditional {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String username;
        System.out.print("username: ");
        username = user_input.next();
            if (username == "test") {
                System.out.println("okay");
                    }
                    else {
                                    System.out.println("not okay");
    }
}
```

The above code does not show any error, it does not display the "okay" && "not okay" message either. I am not sure what's wrong with my logic.

Comment: always use .equals() for string == for reference comparability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @veer said,
you can use [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) / [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)
 `if (username.equals("test")) { ... }`

Or

You can use [`compareToIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) / [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

```
if (username.compareTo("test")==0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

Strings should be compared using `.equals` rather than `==`.  This is the case for all non-primitive comparisons.  For example, you would compare two `int` fields with `==`, but because Strings are not primitive, `.equals` is the correct choice.

```
if (username.equals("test")) {
```

Comment: when and how do you use the ==?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`String.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) here.

```
if (username.equals("test")) {
```

Otherwise, you're comparing the identities of the objects rather than their semantics. In fact, you have two separate `String`s here, which satisfy semantic equality.

Answer (score 0):

Or If you want to use `==` do `username.intern();` Then you can use `==`.

**Note: Not a recommended approch just for FYI.**

Comment: Not `username.intern();` -- that is a statement. You need to use the result of `username.intern()` in your comparison. That all being said, internalized strings are stored in a special part of the heap and are exempt from garbage collection. As a result, if the `String` internally holds a reference to e.g. a larger `char[]` (often the case with `String.substring` results), you can potentially be wasting quite a bit of memory without realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

To compare string you need to use `.equals()` method and also if you need ignore the case of the letters in the String you can use `.equalsIgnoreCase()`

```
 if (username.equals("test")){

 }
 else{

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you do it like this:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
class Conditional {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String username;

        System.out.print("username: ");
        username = user_input.next();

        if (username.equals("test")) {
            System.out.println("okay");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not okay");
        }

        user_input.close();
    }
}
```

A few remarks:

- Class names should start with an upper case.
- Use `equals` to compare `String`s.
- You state that no result is printed at all. You will have to click in the console to type your answer and end the input with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.