# Does String.intern() change reference of Original String JDK7

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [intern() behaving differently in Java 6 and Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065337/intern-behaving-differently-in-java-6-and-java-7)

While doing example for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275251/java-conditional-statement/12275353#12275353)

I noticed a strange behaviour of `intern()` method when I call `intern()` method on `String` thereafter I can use `==` operator for the *Original String*.

JavaDoc of `intern()` method:

> Returns a canonical representation for the string object. 
>   A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String.
>
> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the `equals(Object)` method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.
>
> It follows that for any two strings `s` and `t`, `s.intern() == t.intern()` is true if and only if `s.equals(t)` is true.

Above Javadoc does not say that the *orginal string* gets changed. So why this program prints `okay` when `test` is the input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String username;
        System.out.print("username: ");
        username = user_input.next();
        // Even if I do not assign returned string for comparison still it compares
        // okay else it does not compare
        username.intern();
        if (username == "test") {
            System.out.println("okay");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("not okay");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `intern()` call *should not* be able to influence the result of the test below.

Comment: @JoachimSauer interestingly it does. Just tried it with the latest Java7.

Comment: Tried with java 6 and prints "not okay".

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: indeed, I just verified it with Java 7 as well (Java 6 prints "not okay" as expected). A possible explanation is that Java 7 builds the constant pool lazily, that could result in the in-code `"test"` effectively using the user-provided `"test"` String instance.

Comment: The only relevant noted change in Java 7 I could find was [this RFE](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6962931). A comment also notes the effect described herein, but it's not discussed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String.intern() returns the intern()ed String.  This is because a method cannot change a reference passed to it.

> So why this program prints okay when test is the input.

It prints okay because the intern()ed string is the first time this String is seen so it becomes the one String literal for "test".  It is not the String which is changed, but the object which is used for "test" which is changed.

Try instead.

```
String te = "te", st = "st";
// "test".length();
String username = te + st;
username.intern();
System.out.println("String object the same is: "+ (username == "test"));
```

In this case, the output in Java 7 update 7 is

```
String object the same is: test
```

but run this on Java 6 update 32 or uncomment the line so "test" is seen first and you get.

```
String object the same is: false
```

Comment: But it is changing original string reference. I am using JDK7.

Comment: What you are suggesting is impossible in Java for any method so, no it is not.

Comment: @AmitD Added an example to demonstrate the difference. It is the String literal which is changed, not your `username` string.

Comment: I assume that (in addition to the RFE linked in the comments and the duplicate candidate) a change in Java 7 is that string literals are searched/instantiated (more) lazily now. I was under the impression that Java loaded all relevant String literals of a class at load time ('though I have no references for this).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Good point, have noted that Java 6 doesn't do this.

Answer (score 2):

str.intern() checks to see if there is already the same object in String pool and if so, reuses it.

Comment: That is correct, however the returned reference should be the pooled string. It should not change the reference from within the method.

Answer (score 0):

Below line give you the input form user.

```
    username = user_input.next();
```

After that you are calling `username.intern();` which returns the String literal  of `username`
Now in your condition statement

```
if (username == "test")
```

your variable `username` contain your String literal object from string pool and `"test"` is also a String literal so jvm is going to give you same reference of String `test` which is already created for `username`
that means `username` and `"test"` are the same object.
And in java `==` operated check reference for the object so in this case it will return `true` 
thats why its prints  `okay`